# WebUntisAPI returns "not Authenticated" after calling method in WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, api

To keep it short:
Following method calls a method from the WebUntisAPI (here we look for all rooms):

(this.sessionID has stored the session ID i requested in a authenticationmethod before)

```
public void getRooms()
        {
            client.AddHandler(new JsonDeserializer(), "application/json-rpc");

            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/jason");

            request.AddJsonBody(new
            {
                id = this.sessionID,
                method = "getRooms",
                @params = new {},
                jsonrpc = "2.0"
            });

            var response = this.client.Execute(request);
            var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetRoomsResponse>(response.Content);

            try
            {
                foreach (GetRoomsResult i in deserialized.res)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i.name);
                }
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Something wrong with deserialization!");
            }
        }
```

The Problem is, that the response of the is as followed:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"030BDA942554038735AE69C94D6B0491","error":{"message":"not authenticated","code":-8520}}
```

But the fun is not over yet!
If i copy the created json body and put him into postman, with the same key which is in the this.sessionID variable (of course also the same URL) it is working just fine.
If i generate the sessionID outside the programm and hardcode it to the variable it doesn't work as well.

Anybody already worked with the WebUntisAPI and knows why this doesn't work?

I think maybe it has nothing to do with WebUntis but with the way WPF works after compiling. I really don't know.

Thanks for any advice and help,
Fabian

edit:
[WebUntisAPI documentation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14ahAhOoHA-2lsdsgzRZdGcFyJQvjmW77/view?usp=sharing) i got/found if you want to read it yourself

Comment: Have you tried using a proxy like Fiddler to check exactly what you are sending in the request?

Comment: The document says : All other methods require the result from authentication ( = sessionId), either per pathparameter
;jsessionid=644AFBF2C1B592B68C6B04938BD26965
or per cookie (RequestHeader). 
JSESSIONID=644AFBF2C1B592B68C6B04938BD26965, how are you first authenticatiing?

Comment: @L0uis I am executing the authentication method with username ane PW and store the sessionID in the variable callef session ID

Comment: Looks like the session id has to be in the header of your post request with jsessionid as the header key.